# Firebase query doesn't seems to work in andorid

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing a very wired problem in firebase database when I tried to query my user_name field to check if it already exists in the database or not. It was working earlier but it suddenly stopped working ... Here is my code :

```
 Query query = myRef.child(getString(R.string.usersNode)).orderByChild("user_name").equalTo("codeni8");
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    Log.d(TAG,"username already exist");
                }else {
                    Log.d(TAG,"username does't exist");
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

I don't know why but every time i run it . Its saying "username does't exist" even though it actually exist in the database.

[image: my firebase database]

I don't know what to do. I think the problem started 
when I updated my firebase dependency to "16.0.5"

Here is my Data model of users class:

```
    public class Users {

    private String user_id;
    private String user_name;
    private String display_name;
    private String email;
    private String profile_photo;
    private String cover_photo;
    private String bio;
    private String website;
    private long posts;
    private long followers;
    private long following;
    private String phone_no;
    private String gender;


    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(String user_id, String user_name, String display_name, String email, String profile_photo, String cover_photo, String bio, String website, long posts, long followers, long following, String phone_no, String gender) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.user_name = user_name;
        this.display_name = display_name;
        this.email = email;
        this.profile_photo = profile_photo;
        this.cover_photo = cover_photo;
        this.bio = bio;
        this.website = website;
        this.posts = posts;
        this.followers = followers;
        this.following = following;
        this.phone_no = phone_no;
        this.gender = gender;
    }


    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getUser_name() {
        return user_name;
    }

    public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }

    public String getDisplay_name() {
        return display_name;
    }

    public void setDisplay_name(String display_name) {
        this.display_name = display_name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getProfile_photo() {
        return profile_photo;
    }

    public void setProfile_photo(String profile_photo) {
        this.profile_photo = profile_photo;
    }

    public String getCover_photo() {
        return cover_photo;
    }

    public void setCover_photo(String cover_photo) {
        this.cover_photo = cover_photo;
    }

    public String getBio() {
        return bio;
    }

    public void setBio(String bio) {
        this.bio = bio;
    }

    public String getWebsite() { return website; }

    public void setWebsite(String website) { this.website = website; }

    public long getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }

    public void setPosts(long posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    public long getFollowers() {
        return followers;
    }

    public void setFollowers(long followers) {
        this.followers = followers;
    }

    public long getFollowing() {
        return following;
    }

    public void setFollowing(long following) {
        this.following = following;
    }

    public String getPhone_no() {
        return phone_no;
    }

    public void setPhone_no(String phone_no) {
        this.phone_no = phone_no;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE :**
I am getting this warning on my "user_name" field :

"Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "user_name"' at users to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance"

Is this causing the issue?? How can i add indexOn

**Problem Solved :**
I think ".indexOn" was the issue and also i was using firebase offline features and forgot to sync the particular node, i just did "nodeRefrence.keepSynced(true)" and now every thing is working..

Comment: This is weird, it it happening always from now, or has it just happened first time?

Comment: Not always...Earlier in the same app it was working but after updating the firebase dependancy to 16.0.5 it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: What is the value of `myRef`? What does `getString(R.string.usersNode)` return? Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo myRef is the root reference of the database and usersNode is the node "users"

Comment: Have you tried to print the content of `dataSnapshot`? What is the data inside?

Comment: This is what it shows : "DataSnapshot { key = users, value = null }"

Comment: @AlexMamo updated the question...Can you help?

Comment: The code and JSON look like they should work together. The warning about the index can't cause this problem, although it's great to see that Alex helped you get rid of the warning. I'd like to see the actual JSON as text, instead of a screenshot. Can you add this to your question? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Hey  @Frank van Puffelen i have exported the jason file...How can i attach that file here ?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Here is the json file link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bxZq49e3XBZjlJi33HpZQankhJ1JX5gf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your edited question:

> "Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "user_name"' at users to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance"

It sounds like you may not have defined an index on the field you're querying on. If there is no index, the filtering cannot be done on the server. So in that case the server sends all data to the client, which does the filtering.

> Is this causing the issue? How can i add indexOn?

If this is indeed the cause of your problem, you can fix it by adding an index in your rules file. Knowing that you are ordering `users` node on a property called `user_name`, you should use the following lines of code:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": "user_name"
    }
  }
}
```

For more information about this topic, I recommend you see the official documentation regarding [indexing data in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data).

Comment: I updated my rulles : {
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth!=null" ,
    ".write":"auth!=null" ,
    
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": ["user_name", "email"]
    }
  }
} but still the problem persists

Comment: Try to use only this `".indexOn": "user_name"`, does it work this way?

Comment: Is not working but this warning `"Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "user_name"'` it is still displayed?

Comment: warning is gone

Comment: Good to hear that, another issue is solved but still not the initial one.

Comment: So you are basically saying that if you are using `myRef.child(getString(R.string.usersNode)).orderByChild("display_name").equalTo("codeni8");` works fine but when you are using `myRef.child(getString(R.string.usersNode)).orderByChild("user_name").equalTo("codeni8");` you always get this message: `Log.d(TAG,"username does't exist");`, right?

Comment: Not working anymore earlier it was working...but now it just stopped working. Even in the email field it doesn't work any more...Its just returning null.

Comment: So to understand better, none of your properties are working now in the query, right? Even if is `user_name`, or `display_name` or even `email`, is this correct?

Comment: If you try to use this: `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());` what is the output?

Comment: absolutely nothing

Comment: In this case, please share your enire code somehow to see it more clearly.

Comment: @ Alex Mamo Problem solved , i just cleared the app data and it worked..May be because offline persistence was turned on..I think the ".indexOn" was the issue

Comment: Good to hear that :)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts...I just upvoted your answer

Answer (score 0):

pass id into query like this way..

```
 String userId = mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey();
myRef.child(getString(R.string.usersNode)).child(userId).orderByChild("user_name").equalTo("codeni8");
```

try this method this is working for me.

```
 private void initView() {
    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("usersDb/UserTable");

    mRvData = findViewById(R.id.rvData);
    mTvEmpty = findViewById(R.id.dlTvEmpty);
    mRvData.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mUserList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                // here check id that available or not into db.
                User user = dataSnapshot1.getValue(User.class);

                mUserList.add(user);
            }
            allDataAdapter = new DisplayAllData(DisplayActivity.this, mUserList);
            mRvData.setAdapter(allDataAdapter);
            allDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (mUserList.isEmpty())
                mTvEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                mTvEmpty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

more information refer this link 
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-working-with-firebase-realtime-database/

Comment: I don't just wana search in a particular uid . I want to search that username in the whole database...

Comment: i add one method initview() check this method it help full.